# Android LibGDX 2d remove items on collision, crash

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm try when shot collision with StaticBody delete/remove this body

```
        if ((fixtureB == obstacleFixture) && (fixtureA == shootFixture)) {
           // destroy();
            obstacleBody.destroyFixture(obstacleFixture);

        }
```

But in this part of the code, when have contact, all app crash, and don't know why.

```
File: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/libgdx/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/jni/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.cpp, Line 216

Expression: m_world->IsLocked() == false
```

Actually, I'm a little lost with this library, making it basically creates a triangle and a rectangle and when you click, shoot, now when the shot collides with the triangle, the triangle must disappear. But directly across the APP crash

```
public class Box2DScreen extends MyScreenAdapter {
    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer renderer;
    private OrthographicCamera camara;

    private Body playerBody;
    private Fixture playerFixture;

    private Body shootBody;
    private Fixture shootFixture;
    private Body floorBody;
    private Fixture floorFixture;
    private Body obstacleBody;
    private Fixture obstacleFixture;

    private boolean mustJump = false;
    private boolean isShooting = false;
    private boolean jumping = false;
    private boolean shooting = false;
    private boolean playerLive = true;

    public Box2DScreen(MainGame game) {
        super(game);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true);
        renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        camara = new OrthographicCamera(16.00f, 9.00f);
        camara.translate(0, 1);
        world.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {
            @Override
            public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
                Fixture fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
                Fixture fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();

                if ((fixtureA.getUserData().equals("player")) && (fixtureB.getUserData().equals("floor"))) {
                    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
                        mustJump = true;
                    }
                    jumping = false;
                }

                if ((fixtureA.getUserData().equals("floor")) && (fixtureB.getUserData().equals("player"))) {
                    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
                        mustJump = true;
                    }
                    jumping = false;
                }
                if ((fixtureA.getUserData().equals("player")) && (fixtureB.getUserData().equals("obstacle"))) {
                    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
                        playerLive = false;
                    }
                }
                if ((fixtureA.getUserData().equals("obstacle")) && (fixtureB.getUserData().equals("player"))) {
                    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
                        playerLive = false;
                    }
                }

                if ((fixtureA.getUserData().equals("obstacle")) && (fixtureB.getUserData().equals("shoot"))) {
                    //destroy();
                        obstacleBody.destroyFixture(obstacleFixture);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void endContact(Contact contact) {
                Fixture fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
                Fixture fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();

                if ((fixtureA == playerFixture) && (fixtureB == floorFixture)) {
                    jumping = true;
                }
                if ((fixtureB == playerFixture) && (fixtureA == floorFixture)) {
                    jumping = true;
                }

                if ((fixtureA == shootFixture) && (fixtureB == obstacleFixture)) {
                  //  destroy();

                }
                if ((fixtureB == obstacleFixture) && (fixtureA == shootFixture)) {
                   // destroy();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

            }

            @Override
            public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

            }
        });
        BodyDef playerBodyDef;
        playerBodyDef = createPlayerBodyDef();
        playerBody = world.createBody(playerBodyDef);
        PolygonShape playerShape = new PolygonShape();
        playerShape.setAsBox(0.5f, 0.5f);
        playerFixture = playerBody.createFixture(playerShape, 1);
        playerShape.dispose();

        BodyDef floorBodyDef;
        floorBodyDef = createFloorBodyDef();
        floorBody = world.createBody(floorBodyDef);
        PolygonShape floorShape = new PolygonShape();
        floorShape.setAsBox(500.00f, 1.00f);
        floorFixture = floorBody.createFixture(floorShape, 1);
        floorShape.dispose();

        BodyDef obstacleBodyDef;
        obstacleBodyDef = createObstacleBodyDef(6f);
        obstacleBody = world.createBody(obstacleBodyDef);
        obstacleFixture = createObstacleFixture(obstacleBody);


        playerFixture.setUserData("player");
        floorFixture.setUserData("floor");
        obstacleFixture.setUserData("obstacle");
    }


    private BodyDef createShootBodyDef() {
        BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
        def.position.set(playerBody.getPosition().x + 1f, playerBody.getPosition().y);
        def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        def.gravityScale = 0;
        return def;
    }

    private Fixture createObstacleFixture(Body obstacle) {
        Vector2[] vertices = new Vector2[3];
        vertices[0] = new Vector2(-0.5f, -0.5f);
        vertices[1] = new Vector2(0.5f, -0.5f);
        vertices[2] = new Vector2(0, 0.5f);

        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.set(vertices);

        Fixture fix = obstacle.createFixture(shape, 1);
        shape.dispose();
        return fix;
    }

    private BodyDef createObstacleBodyDef(float x) {
        BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
        def.position.set(x, 0.5f);
        def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;

        return def;
    }

    private BodyDef createPlayerBodyDef() {
        BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
        def.position.set(0, 0.5f);
        def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        return def;
    }

    private BodyDef createFloorBodyDef() {
        BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
        def.position.set(0, -1);
        def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
        return def;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        playerBody.destroyFixture(playerFixture);
        floorBody.destroyFixture(floorFixture);
        obstacleBody.destroyFixture(obstacleFixture);
        shootBody.destroyFixture(shootFixture);

        world.destroyBody(playerBody);
        world.destroyBody(floorBody);
        world.destroyBody(obstacleBody);
        world.destroyBody(shootBody);

        world.dispose();
        renderer.dispose();

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (mustJump) {
            mustJump = false;
            saltar();
        }
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched() && !jumping) {
            mustJump = true;
        }
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched() && shooting) {
            destroy();
        }

        if (Gdx.input.justTouched() && !shooting) {
            BodyDef shootBodyDef;
            shootBodyDef = createShootBodyDef();
            shootBody = world.createBody(shootBodyDef);
            PolygonShape shootShape = new PolygonShape();
            shootShape.setAsBox(0.3f, 0.09f);
            shootFixture = shootBody.createFixture(shootShape, 1);
            shootShape.dispose();
            shootFixture.setUserData("shoot");
            shooting = true;
        }


        if (shooting) {
            float velocidadY = shootBody.getLinearVelocity().y;
            shootBody.setLinearVelocity(6, velocidadY);
        }
        if (playerLive) {
            float velocidadY = playerBody.getLinearVelocity().y;
            playerBody.setLinearVelocity((float) 0.7, velocidadY);
        }


        world.step(delta, 6, 2);
        camara.update();
        renderer.render(world, camara.combined);
    }

    private void saltar() {
        Vector2 position = playerBody.getPosition();
        playerBody.applyLinearImpulse(0, 6, position.x, position.y, true);
    }
    private void destroy(){
        shooting = false;
        shootBody.destroyFixture(shootFixture);
        world.destroyBody(shootBody);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your app crashes, you register the reason in your logcat. Please post it.

Comment: File: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/libgdx/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/jni/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.cpp, Line 216

Expression: m_world->IsLocked() == false
its only have

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the body while it's colliding, box2d is doing math and will go nuts if you remove it, the best way to do this is to set the setActive(false) and remove it later on an iteration inside on your render method, like this:

```
            [...]
private List<Fixture> lstRemoveFixture = new ArrayList<>();
            [...]
            @Override
            public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
                Fixture fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
                Fixture fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();

               if(fixtureA != null and fixtureB != null){
                     [...]
                     if ((fixtureA.getUserData().equals("obstacle")) && (fixtureB.getUserData().equals("shoot"))) {
                         //destroy();
                        obstacleBody.setActive(false);
                        lstRemoveFixture.add(obstacleFixture);
                      }
               }
            }
```

And on your render method:

```
public void render(float delta) {
      [...]
         world.step(delta, 6, 2);
         for(Fixture fixture : lstRemoveFixture){
             obstacleBody.destroyFixture(fixture);
             lstRemoveFixture.remove(fixture);
         }
         obstacleBody.setActive(true);
      [...]
  }
```

Comment: this obstacleFixture.setActive(false); maybe it should be obstacleBody.setActive(false); ?

Comment: my bad, i don't have access to IDE with Libgdx to test here from my work,  well if your obstaclebody have multiple fixtures all fixtures inherit gonna stop processing collision, so you should set it active later at 1 frame cost, gonna edit the awnser..

Comment: continuous return same error Expression: m_world->IsLocked() == false